Scss - How to add suffix and select as direct child element
Here is my code:
.a {
  > .b {
    > .c {
      & > &__content {
        background: black;
      }
    }
  }
}

What I want:
.a > .b > .c > .c__content {
  background: black;
}

What I actually got:
.a > .b > .c > .a > .b > .c__content {
  background: black;
}

So how can I do it.

You cannot use &__content directly because the & symbol points to its parent (here .c), and it generates .c__content.
To correctly target .a > .b > .c > .c__content, you need to specify the full selector path again. You can do this by using a variable or by writing the class name directly :
$c: ".c";

.a {
  & > .b {
    & > $c {
      & > #{$c}__content {
        background: black;
      }
    }
  }
}

or without using a variable :
.a {
  & > .b {
    & > .c {
      & > .c__content {
        background: black;
      }
    }
  }
}

This ensures that the __content element is correctly nested within .c, maintaining the correct hierarchy in the BEM methodology.
